# Conditional probability and complement

Tags: probability

$P(A|C)+P(A|C^{\complement})=P(A|C\cup C^{\complement})=P(A)$  ?

I think this is false, but I cannot think of  a counterexample, can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equation is true, because $P(A | C \cup C^\complement) = P(A \cap C)  + P(A \cap C^\complement)$ and that is just a particular case of the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), that is, since $C \cup C^\complement$ is a partition of the sample space, we have $P(A | C \cup C^\complement) = P(A)$.

The problem is with your first equality. If you want a concrete counterexample, take for instance the classic six-face dice with all faces being equally likely, set $A$ for "face 1" and $C$ for "any even face". Then you will see that

$P(A | C) = 0$ and $P(A | C^\complement) = \frac{1}{3}$

but $P(A | C \cup C^\complement) = P(A) = \frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $C=A$ we find $1+0=P(A)$, so counterexample if $P(A)<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $C\cup C^\complement$ equals the sample space, therefore $\mathsf P(A\mid C\cup C^\complement)~=~\mathsf P(A).$

However, by the Law of Total Probability, $~\mathsf P(A)~=~\mathsf P(A\mid C)\;\mathsf P(C)+\mathsf P(A\mid C^\complement)\;\mathsf P(C^\complement)$

So...